# Intersects Filter on WFS 1.0.0

Tags: wfs, filter, mapserver

I use WFS=1.0.0 on the Mapserver v5.6.6 and v6.0.1 with MS4W package. I want to get the Intersects of Spatial Operator. When I make getcapabilities request I see just "Intersect" like: 
ogc:Filter_Capabilities>
- 
- 
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
  
When I change version of WFS to 1.1.0 I see the Intersects Spatial Operator. 
I need get the Intersects on WFS=1.0.0. Is it possible? If so how can I get it?
P.S. When I use Geoserver then it seems to work.

Comment: Hi, could you maybe try to explain step by step what you are trying to do and what software you use and what's not working exactly as desired? It's difficult to catch your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Intersect" is mainly a typo in the OGC Filter encoding standard 1.0 that is also used in WFS 1.0.0. A message thread about this is at
https://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04231.html

Especially this part from the answer by Andrea Aime:
The Filter specification 1.0 states:

```
<xsd:element name="Intersects" type="ogc:BinarySpatialOpType"
substitutionGroup="ogc:spatialOps"/>
```

however filtercapabilties.xsd, referred by wfs 1.0 caps states:

```
 <xsd:element name="Intersect">
      <xsd:complexType/>
   </xsd:element>
```

Thus the name of the filter is Intersects and that's what you need to use in your filter, is is just listed in WFS 1.0.0 GetCapabilities as Intersect.